# net pipe WCF service running in different user sessions with the same endpoint name

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, net.pipe

Based on everything I've read about WCF services using net pipes I expected to be able to use the address net.pipe://localhost/service/ on different user sessions as WCF does not use the name but a GUID.

Anyway when I launch several services I get a `AddressAlreadyInUseException` with the message:

```
Cannot listen on pipe name 'net.pipe://localhost/service/' because another pipe endpoint is already listening on that name.
```

Is there a way to limit the scope of every WCF service to the user session? Connections will come always from the same user session.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21467910/wcf-with-named-pipe-under-different-user-sessions

Comment: That post says exactly the opposite of what is happening to me. If that was true I won't get the AddessAlreadyInUseException. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we have found is that Administrator users can see named piped between sessions while normal users do not see them. So we ended up running the application without admin rights and that was it.

What I don't know if this behavior is something that can be changed or if it is fixed in Windows.