# How to connect to a WCF named pipe created in desktop app from backend of website running locally on an IIS server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, ipc

I am working on a prototype and I need implement inter-process communication between a WPF desktop application and the back-end of a locally hosted ASP.NET website. I was able to get IPC (using named pipes) working between 2 WPF desktop applications using WCF but am having difficulty making this work with the client being the back-end of website instead of a separate desktop application.

My website is hosted locally on my development machine using IIS. Here are some of the settings I have configured in my IIS manager or on my local machine.

- I have enabled the **net.pipe** protocol for my website.
- I have enabled **Named Pipe Activation** via Turn Windows feature on or off > .NET Framework 4.7 Advanced Services > WCF Services.
- I have added a Site Binding of type **net.pipe** with a wildcard * as it's Binding Information.

I run my server desktop application which creates a named pipe using WCF that can be connected to by clients. When I attempt to access my web page, an EndpointNotFoundException is thrown stating **The message could not be dispatched because the service at the endpoint address 'net.pipe://localhost/CessProto' is unavailable for the protocol of the address**.

The client code used to connect to the created endpoint (in both my the controller of my web page & my client desktop application) is shown below.

```
var callback = new CallbackService();
var context = new InstanceContext(callback);
var pipeFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IServerService>(context, 
    new NetNamedPipeBinding(), 
    new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/CessProto"));
_serverService = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
_serverService.Connect();
```

I have a client desktop application with the same code and it can connect to the pipe without issue but when the client is the back end controller of a web page and I attempt to access the web page in my browser, an exception is thrown when the call is made to *Connect()*.

Any idea what might be the issue here?

Thanks

Edit: Changed title & reworded some things.

Comment: My website can connect to the pipe if I run my WPF as an administrator.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WCF security problems with named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300487/wcf-security-problems-with-named-pipes)