# Accessing objects created in windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services

If I was to create a windows service, which in the background was making calls to the database and populating various objects. Is it then possible to access these objects from a standalone C# application? If so, how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use [Named Pipes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-named-pipes-for-network-interprocess-communication) to make communication between two .Net applications.

This should be place inside Service to listen on client applications request

```
private static void SendByteAndReceiveResponse()
 {           
     using (NamedPipeServerStream namedPipeServer = new 
      NamedPipeServerStream("test-pipe"))
     {
    namedPipeServer.WaitForConnection();
    namedPipeServer.WriteByte(1);
    int byteFromClient = namedPipeServer.ReadByte();
    Console.WriteLine(byteFromClient);
  }
}
```

and this will be inside Client applications

```
    private static void ReceiveByteAndRespond()
   {           
      using (NamedPipeClientStream namedPipeClient = new 
      NamedPipeClientStream("test-pipe"))
     {
    namedPipeClient.Connect();
    Console.WriteLine(namedPipeClient.ReadByte());
    namedPipeClient.WriteByte(2);
   }
}
```

**Note**

Please do changes in

> namedPipeClient.WriteByte(2);

according to your business logic.

**OR**

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303154/connecting-via-named-pipe-from-windows-service-session0-to-desktop-app-sessi) thread

Answer (score 0):

Accessing objects strictly speaking is not possible. You can connect your apps with (for example) named pipes as per @Taha Sultan Temuri and serialize your objects, send over and deserialize them on the other end.